# Developing for multiple versions of Firefox

Tags: firefox

Lately, we have noticed that not all Firefox versions are playing the same game when it comes to layout and I wanted to find out if there is a definitive guideline when it comes to developing for Firefox.

What we're having to do is use Portable Versions of FF and then test across these versions but this is becoming a major headache! If someone knows of a script that will fix these issues across different versions of Firefox, I would appreciate it. Else, if there is some guidelines I can follow, I would appreciate that too!

Thanks,
James

Comment: It might help us if you explain the actual problem that you're having - exactly how is firefox bisbehaving, using what code/html? and what do you expect it to do? What other browsers are you testing in and what behaviour do they have given the same code?

Comment: Hey Taryn. It seems to be more generic alignment issues of basic html and css elements on the page. The person testing in the office uses 3.6.8 because she'd like to keep to lower version that other people might be on, but for the other people who have gone on to install versions above this, we get alignment issues. I'm just wondering if other people are experiencing this too?

Comment: Yes, but it would help *us* if you give us some examples - and also what you are comparing them to. Right now you're talking about things that are concrete for you (because you've seen them), but which I personally cannot picture... and I do know that, for example, firefox implements some standards in a more strict sense than other browsers - which means that it might not be firefox that is at issue.... but maybe it is... because I don't know what exact problem you are having. It'd really help us if you gave some real examples.

Comment: Hi Taryn. Unfortunately, we're developing locally at the moment so I cannot show you anything (wish I could) but this has happened numerous times when we are cross-browser testing. It seems the later versions of Firefox render html and css differently which makes it more complicated to cater for all these different browser versions. I was just wondering if someone had a definitive guide of changes Mozilla would have made to their browsers. Thanks again.

Comment: The usual practise is to extract the part that is breaking into a small test example, and change the names to something innocuous. Then show us that.
If you don't give us anything to work with - then we may not be able to help you. (we being the S/O community in general). :(

Comment: Thanks Taryn. Most of the time we just hack away at it until we get something workable but it takes up a lot of our time and I was just wondering if there is something...like  a cheat sheet or best practices document of changes in FF versions we need to be aware of. :)

Comment: Not that I know of. From time to time, there are great articles written about specific problems and how to solve them in multiple browsers... which is why I was digging for specifics - if you have an issue on your mind, there's a potential for us to point you at the solution. But I've never heard of a general cheat sheet. Not that that means it doesn't exist - may well do! Just outside my own scope of knowledge :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior you see might be an intentional change (e.g. to comply with the HTML5 spec) or a bug (a regression). If it is the former it should be listed on https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Firefox_4_for_developers or https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Firefox_5_for_developers. These pages are usually created in advance of a major release (e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Firefox_6_for_developers exists already) so that you can see if something affecting you is coming up. If a change breaks backwards compatibility there should be hints on how web developers can deal with it.

If it is a bug then it should be reported on https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/ along with a minimized testcase, marked with the "regression" keyword. Regressions that are reproducible and that affect web applications usually get looked at pretty quickly.

That's a very broad answer to a very broad question. For more useful answers you should really provide some details with your question.